# How to change Background of HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, java-me, horizontalfieldmanager

I want to set the Background of HorizontalFieldManager.
The sample code I've been searching is setting the background using Gradient for the main screen background.

```
 //create gradient linear for background
 this.getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(0x0099CCFF,
                            0x0099CCFF,0x00336699,0x00336699)
                        );
```

Then I try to use the same pattern to set background to HorizontalFieldManager, since it have this method. But it won't work. Here's the code

```
            HorizontalFieldManager hManager = new HorizontalFieldManager();

    Bitmap bitmapImage = null;

    bitmapImage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/home.png");
    tabHome = new BitmapField(bitmapImage, BitmapField.FOCUSABLE
            | BitmapField.HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS);

    bitmapImage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/in.png");
    tabCheckInOut = new BitmapField(bitmapImage, BitmapField.FOCUSABLE
            | BitmapField.HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS);

    bitmapImage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/barcode.png");
    tabBarcode = new BitmapField(bitmapImage, BitmapField.FOCUSABLE
            | BitmapField.HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS);

    bitmapImage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/options.png");
    tabOptions = new BitmapField(bitmapImage, BitmapField.FOCUSABLE
            | BitmapField.HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS);

    tabHome.setFocusListener(this);
    tabCheckInOut.setFocusListener(this);
    tabBarcode.setFocusListener(this);
    tabOptions.setFocusListener(this);

    Background topBack = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0x00606A85);
    hManager.setBackground(topBack);

    hManager.add(tabHome);
    hManager.add(tabCheckInOut);
    hManager.add(tabBarcode);
    hManager.add(tabOptions);

    add(hManager);
```

I'm using HorizontalFieldManager and add 4 BitmapField, then I using BackgroundFactory to create solidBackground, and set it to the manager
but when I run it, the background color does not apply. The gradient example work well. Is there anything that I'm missing? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You can post your solution has an answer and accept it

Comment: Actually, I would say that you _should_ post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: can you check whether the following code helps you, I am not sure ...  hfmthree  =  new HorizontalFieldManager(){
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
     graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     super.paint(graphics);
    }
   };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some deep web search. Here's the answer guys

```
HorizontalFieldManager manager = new HorizontalFieldManager()
{
    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x000000FF);//blue
        graphics.clear();
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
};
```

**UPDATE:**
You must only use Web Color
such as 0x006699FF should work
but 0x00606A85 would not work.
if you want a specific color, i recommend you using bitmap.

**UPDATE:**
Another solution

```
 HorizontalFieldManager manager = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
 manager.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.BackgroundFactory
            .createSolidBackground(0x00cccccc));
```

Comment: I set the USE_ALL_WIDTH in the constructor.
HorizontalFieldManager manager = new HorizontalFieldManager( USA_ALL_WIDTH ) ... etc